# Reference to a Spring GenericBeanDefinition

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to define my beans programmatically. I have 1 DAO bean, used by 2 other services beans. The DAO bean is injected as a constructor argument.

How can I get a reference to the DAO bean to build the service beans (analog to <bean ref="myDAO"/>) ?

My DAO is defined as (with DefaultListableBeanFactory beanFactory):

```
final GenericBeanDefinition myDAODefinition = new GenericBeanDefinition();
myDAODefinition.setBeanClassName("com.xxx.dao");
final BeanDefinitionHolder myDAOHolder = new BeanDefinitionHolder(myDAODefinition,"myDAO");
BeanDefinitionReaderUtils.registerBeanDefinition(myDAOHolder, beanFactory);
```

Then my services beans:

```
final GenericBeanDefinition srv1Definition = new GenericBeanDefinition();
srv1Definition.setBeanClassName("com.xxx.service1");
srv1Definition.setConstructorArgumentValues(new ConstructorArgumentValues() {
 {
  addGenericArgumentValue(*** ref to "myDAO" holder ***);
 }
});
final BeanDefinitionHolder srv1Holder = new BeanDefinitionHolder(srv2Definition, "srv1");
```

and:

```
final GenericBeanDefinition srv2Definition = new GenericBeanDefinition();
srv2Definition.setBeanClassName("com.xxx.service2");
srv2Definition.setConstructorArgumentValues(new ConstructorArgumentValues() {
 {
  addGenericArgumentValue(*** ref to "myDAO" holder ***);
 }
});
final BeanDefinitionHolder srv2Holder = new BeanDefinitionHolder(srv2Definition, "srv2");
```

How to reference "myDAO" Holder to inject it twice in other definitions ?

Note that I cannot use annotations.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Found out, just use:

```
Object myDAORef = new RuntimeBeanReference("myDAO");
```

and inject it as the constructor argument.